# downgrade a ffi gem to support ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have downgraded Ruby Version due to some limitations. Now when I do `bundle update` it keep giving me error and halts in between:

```
Gem::InstallError: ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0.
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.18), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.18'` succeeds before bundling.
```

As per this error I should have Ruby version greater than 2.0 and less than 2.5 to install `ffi`. Is their a `ffi` version compatible to `ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]`? If yes, where to specify it, I have tried changing it to 1.9.10 in Gemfile.lock but still kept on giving above error about upgrading Ruby version.

I am stuck here, what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here with exactly the same ruby version!

ffi version 1.9.8 worked for me: `gem isntall ffi -v 1.9.8`

Hope that helps and that it's not to late!